# ReactiveMongo: single connection pool instance Vs many connection pool instances Vs multiple connection pools

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I am using ReactiveMongo 0.12, and trying to understand the core differences between how different types of connection pooling works in ReactiveMongo.

ReactiveMongo seems to provide 3 ways in which we can establish connection with the database:

**TYPE 1: Using Single Connection Pool Instance**

```scala
import reactivemongo.api.MongoConnection
val driver1 = new reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver
val connection3 = driver1.connection(List("addressA: 27017", "addressB: 27017","addressC": 27017", "addressD: 27017"))
```

**TYPE 2: Using multiple Connection Pool Instances**

```scala
import reactivemongo.api.MongoConnection
val driver1 = new reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver
val connection1 = driver1.connection(List("addressA", "addressB"))
val connection2 = driver1.connection(List("addressC", "addressD"))
```

**TYPE 3: Using multiple connection pools**

```scala
import reactivemongo.api.MongoConnection
val driver1 = new reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver // first pool
  val driver2 = new reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver // second pool

  // Pick a connection from the first pool
  def connection1 = driver1.connection(List("addressA", "addressB"))

  // Pick a connection from the second pool
  def connection2 = driver2.connection(List("addressC", "addressD"))
```

What are the differences between these 3 types of connection ? Which would be the best approach in terms of performance?

Comment: You can use the [MailingList](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/reactivemongo) to ask question.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/connect-database.html), on one side there are the heavyweight types `MongoDriver` and `MongoConnection` (heavy meaning they are managing many resources, as network channels).

As it can be read in the documentation, "`MongoDriver` holds the actor system" (Akka as implementation details : "the driver creates a new actor system") while "`MongoConnection` the references to the actors" managing the connection pool ("creating network channels").

On the other hand as mentioned, "`DefaultDB` and `Collection` are just plain objects that store references and nothing else. Getting such references is lightweight".

- So *case 1* is using a single `ActorSystem` (which as memory and CPU
  cost), and a single connection pool.
- The *case 2* differs from the first one as it
  defines 2 connection pools, which could only make sense if using
  different nodes (ReplicaSet), or the same nodes with different
  connection options.
- Finally *case 3* differs from the second one using multiple drivers, and so multiple `ActorSystem`, which make quite no sense (except in very specific case, e.g. for testing).